# Optimal way to create instances from metadata dump

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metadata, google-compute-engine

I am looking for the most optimal way (probably using gcloud) to recreate new instances when they are being restored from snapshot.

```
gcloud compute instances describe --format json [instance-name]
```

The command above will give me a metadata dump of the instance details (machine type, network, network tags, ssh keys etc.....) How can I use this data to create a new instance and/or pass this information when restoring from snapshot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you dump the metadata from an instance you get a lot of information than you can't/shouldn't use to create a new instance, for example the instance ID, the IP, etc, but you have the option to [create a instance template from another instance][1] overriding the source disk for one you can create from the snapshot.

1 - Create a Snapshot

2 - Create a template from your source instance

3 - Go to your "VM instances" dashboard, and select "Create instance -> from template"

4 - Select template and "OK"

5 - On boot disk select "change", then under the "snapshots tab" select the snapshot.

6 - Deploy the instance